# I am getting this ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged error. Can anyone resolve?

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning

I want to plot the data according to the classes given using Support Vector Machine. I am stuck in this code.

Error is shown at ->  Z = Z.reshape(XX.shape)

Please note the code is imported from [sklearn-svm](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_kernels.html#example-svm-plot-svm-kernels-py). When I try to change the datasets given to the application the above error is shown.

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from sklearn import svm,datasets

    iris = datasets.load_iris()
    X = iris.data[:, :2]  # we only take the first two features. We could
                             # avoid this ugly slicing by using a two-dim dataset
    Y = iris.target
    Y = np.array(Y)
    # figure number
    fignum = 1

    # fit the model
    for kernel in ('linear', 'poly', 'rbf'):
        clf = svm.SVC(kernel=kernel, gamma=2)
        clf.fit(X, Y)

        # plot the line, the points, and the nearest vectors to the plane
        plt.figure(fignum, figsize=(4, 3))
        plt.clf()

        plt.scatter(clf.support_vectors_[:, 0], clf.support_vectors_[:, 1], s=80,
                    facecolors='none', zorder=10)
        plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=Y, zorder=10, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)

        plt.axis('tight')
        x_min = 0
        x_max = 10
        y_min = 0
        y_max = 10

        XX, YY = np.mgrid[x_min:x_max:200j, y_min:y_max:200j]
        Z = clf.decision_function(np.c_[XX.ravel(), YY.ravel()])
        # Put the result into a color plot
        Z = Z.reshape(XX.shape)
        #print Z
        plt.figure(fignum, figsize=(4, 3))
        plt.pcolormesh(XX, YY, Z > 0, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)
        plt.contour(XX, YY, Z, colors=['k', 'k', 'k'], linestyles=['--', '-', '--'],levels=[-.5, 0, .5])
        plt.xlim(x_min, x_max)
        plt.ylim(y_min, y_max)

        plt.xticks(())
        plt.yticks(())
        fignum = fignum + 1
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Please be more precise. Post more information, e.g. where does the error occur? Posting the traceback would help a lot. Just posting source that others should fix is not the way SO works.

Answer (score 1):

`XX` and `YY` both have the shape `(200, 200)`, but your `Z` has shape `(40000, 3)`. So `XX` and `YY` both contain 40000 values, while Z has 120000 values and can therefore not simply be reshaped to the shape of `XX` or `YY` as you would lose values. The call to `decision_function()` does not return a matrix of shape `(N_samples, 1)` as you seem to expect. Instead, according to [scikit documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.decision_function), it returns `(N_samples, n_class * (n_class-1) / 2)`. You can replace the call with `predict()` to get the (probably) desired result, i.e.

```
Z = clf.predict(np.c_[XX.ravel(), YY.ravel()])
```

[image: svm result]